# How get coordinates from MediaWiki

Tags: jquery, ajax, coordinates, mediawiki

I have to do a web interface with a map inside... this map should take the coordinates of some place/city/or something else from the Wikipedia database.
I read something about MediaWiki api but i can't understand how to use it.
At this moment i found this code to take a text from Wikipedia and to put it in a div:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=Rome&callback=?",

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
        var blurb = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
        $('#list').html($(blurb).find('p'));

    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
    }
});
```

So I have to change the URL request but I don't understand how.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get coordinate data out of Wikidata, using the [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org) (WDS).

For example, the [following query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%20.%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%28STR%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22Rome%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fplace%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20.%0A%20%20%23filter%28lang%28%3Fplace%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%23filter%28str%28%3Farticle%29%20%3D%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRome%22%29%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010%0A) (not very tested) will return some information about things called Rome that have coordinates:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?place wdt:P625 ?location .
  ?place rdfs:label ?label .
  FILTER(LANG(?label) = "en") .
  FILTER(STR(?label) = "Rome") .
  ?article schema:about ?place .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
} LIMIT 10
```

You can get the JSON representation of this with a URL like:

```
https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql?query=<URL-encoded query here>
```

Comment: this query is perfect for my case...but this is a sparql query so how can i insert it on a html file?

Comment: The JSON  URL I gave at the bottom can be used in your `$.ajax` call. You'll have to modify how you handle the response, of course.